Mouse clicks don't work in Windows 11
Sometimes, around a few times a week, my mouse clicks no longer work in Windows 11. It happens out of nowhere, such as when browsing the internet. I can interact with everything using the keyboard, and my scroll wheel works, but not any clicks. Whenever I click with the mouse button, left or right, whatever application I have in focus loses focus. I can still alt tab to focus onto any app.
If I hit CTRL+ALT+DEL to open up the black screen with a menu, after a second or two my mouse clicks start working. I can then click cancel and it is all working again and I won't run into the issue for another few days.
I used an app called Focus Logger, and started it up when this issue happened. Whenever I clicked with the mouse button, the application that would come into focus was a process named "Idle" and path "System Idle Process" with no window name. You can see a screenshot of it below.

I thought it was an anomaly with only my PC, but then I just set up someone else's PC with a brand new Windows 11, and they ran into the same issue after a few days.

Did you accidentally turn off the mouse cursor?

A lot of users accidentally turn off the mouse pointer via their keyboard. The key F5 is generally used to disable the mouse so try pressing F5. If that doesn’t work then try (function key) FN + F5 or FN + F9 if you are using ASUS or FN + F7 if you are using an Acer machine.

Reference: https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-cursor-disappearing-on-windows-10/

The cursor is still visible when this issue occurs, and hitting all those key combos while the cursor is working doesn't seem to have any effect.

try to use mouse on keyboard and see if the same problem exist, by clicking the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking Ease of Access, then click Ease of Access Center, Click Make the mouse easier to use, Under Control the mouse with the keyboard, select the Turn on Mouse Keys check box.
